# how to fix loop iteration in lists

Tags: python

There is 2500 images which i want to stack in 250 sequences in a list as "img_seq_list" to feed a deep neural network. the code is as below, as run the code, below ERROR is given. i was wonder if someone helps to fix it.Thank you

ERROR:
need at least one array to stack

```
import numpy as np
import glob
from PIL import Image

images = glob.glob("*.png")
img_seq_list = []
for i in range(len(images) + 1): 
    j = i+10       
    img_seq = np.stack(images[i:j], axis=0)
img_seq_list.append(img_seq)
i=i+10
```

Edited code is as below:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
from PIL import Image
images = glob.glob("*.png")
img_seq_list = []
for i in range(0, len(images) - 10): 
    j = i+10       
    img_seq = np.stack(images[i:j], axis=0)
    img_seq_list.append(img_seq)
```

Comment: Do you have a syntax error within the question? I'm confused why you're appending outside of the loop and also increment `i` outside of the loop, which will already increment `i`....

Comment: I have tried appen () both in for loop and out of for loop. yes you are right about i+10 i can use j instead of i. i want to have i+10 to pass through 10 images which have appended

Comment: no. no syntax error

Comment: There's just a lot that's potentially wrong here. 
1. You keep setting `img_seq` without doing anything with it
2. You are looping through the length of images which is 0 indexed, but adding 1 to the loop AND trying to go 10 past with `j`. So that probably doesn't actually exist.
3. You are trying to increment `i` after the for loop.

I'm not 100% sure on your goal here, but you might want `for i in range(0, len(images) -  10, 10):`